# Converting TWIG to PHP Syntax

Tags: php, twig

```
<td class="text-left">
      <select name="product[{{ list_row }}][status]" id="input-status" class="form-control">
          {% if i.status %}
            <option value="1" selected="selected">{{ text_enabled }}</option>
        <option value="0">{{ text_disabled }}</option>
             {% else %}
             <option value="1">{{ text_enabled }}</option>
               <option value="0" selected="selected">{{ text_disabled }}</option>
             {% endif %}
      </select>
</td>
    <td class="text-left">
           <button id="button_cancel" type="button" onclick="$('#product_row_{{ list_row }}').remove()" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_remove }}" class="btn btn-danger">
      <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
        </button>
          </td> 
             </tr>
       {% set list_row = list_row + 1 %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

For above code "Select" how should i convert it to php syntax?

> Same goes to set list_row = list_row +1 ? what is %} < means ?

Comment: Curious, why are you wanting to convert Twig to PHP, instead of using the Twig templates? Twig has a ton of useful features for making templates like `{% extends %}` and helps to keep your templates free of business logic. It's definitely worth learning.

Comment: Yeah i wanted to learn as it was new to me , but i was passed to this project and unable to proceed for enchancement due to the syntax and it was slowing down the project.

Comment: you can convert your twig code here : https://www.easycodetools.com/tool/twig-to-php-converter

Answer (score 2):

There is not much different from the syntax of PHP and Twig. Twig offers a pure templating perspective from PHP, in order to help keep your templates free of business logic and provides capabilities like auto-escaping of HTML entities and Javascript, and silently ignoring undefined variable, array indexes or object methods/properties, similar to the `??` (null coalesce) operator in PHP .

I highly recommend that you take a day and learn the very limited syntax that Twig has https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/ there are subtle differences between versions 1, 2 and 3. With a great explanation of how twig works in https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html

**Twig Output**

```
{{ var|e }}
```

Is the equivalent to

```php
<?php echo htmlspecialchars((isset($var) ? $var : null), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
```

**Twig Variable Declarations**

```
{% set var = 'value' %}
```

Is the equivalent to

```php
<?php $var = 'value'; ?>
```

So `{{ }}` can be thought of as a shortcut for printing output `<?php echo ?>` or rather `<?= ?>`.
Where `{% %}` are open and close twig statement delimiters and can be thought of similarly to the open and close PHP statement delimiters `<?php ?>`.

It is important to note, that twig does not have access to the PHP globals or namespace. So something like `<?php foreach ($vars as $i => $var) { ?>` is handled differently in twig, for this instance `{% for i, var in vars %}`.

**Twig Variable Access**

Twig is also able to access both associative array keys and object properties with the same syntax `var.property`, with the ability to automatically call `get`, `is` and `has` methods of an object.

If `var` is an array, `{{ var.property }}` is the equivalent to

```
$var = ['property' => 'value'];

echo htmlspecialchars(($var['property'] ?? null), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); //PHP 7.0+
echo htmlspecialchars((array_key_exists('property', $var) ? $var['property'] : null), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); //PHP < 7.0
```

if `var` is an object, `{{ var.property }}` is the equivalent to

```
class Var
{
    private $property = 'value';

    public function getProperty()
    {
       return $property;
    }
}
$var = new Var();

if (isset($var->property)) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($var->property, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
} elseif (is_callable([$var, 'property'])) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($var->property(), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
} elseif (is_callable([$var, 'getProperty'])) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($var->getProperty(), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
} elseif (is_callable([$var, 'isProperty'])) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($var->isProperty(), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
} elseif (is_callable([$var, 'hasProperty'])) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($var->hasProperty(), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
} else {
    echo null;
}
```

---

There are portions of your template missing. Such as the template variables and the beginning of your `if` and `for ... in` blocks. To provide a more complete example, I included some assertions of what the variables and the beginning `if` and `foreach` statements would look like.

To convert the Twig template you supplied to PHP, it would look similar to the below.

```
<?php
/* START ASSERTIONS */

$iterable = [
    ['status' => true],
];
$test_enabled = 'Enabled';
$text_disabled = 'Disabled';
$button_remove = 'Remove';

if (!empty($iterable)) {
    $list_row = 0;
    foreach ($iterable as $i) { 
?>
<tr>
<?php /* END ASSERTIONS */ ?>

<td class="text-left">
    <select name="product[<?php echo htmlspecialchars($list_row, ENT_QUOTE, 'UTF-8'); ?>][status]" id="input-status" class="form-control">
    <?php if (array_key_exists('status', $i) ? $i['status'] : null) { ?>
        <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text_enabled, ENT_QUOTE, 'UTF-8'); ?></option>
        <option value="0"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text_disabled, ENT_QUOTE, 'UTF-8'); ?></option>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <option value="1"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text_enabled, ENT_QUOTE, 'UTF-8'); ?></option>
        <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text_disabled, ENT_QUOTE, 'UTF-8'); ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
</td>
<td class="text-left">
    <button id="button_cancel" type="button" onclick="$('#product_row_<?php echo htmlspecialchars($list_row, ENT_QUOTE, 'UTF-8'); ?>').remove()" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($button_remove, ENT_QUOTE, 'UTF-8'); ?>" class="btn btn-danger">
        <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
    </button>
</td> 
</tr>
<?php 
    $list_row = $list_row + 1;
    } /* endfor */
} /* endif */
?>
```